# How can I make Nokie HERE map polyline using object of lat long in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, nokia, here-api

Here is my code:

```
$.each(data, function (i, val) {

    salesmanTrackPoints[val.id] = new Array();

    var coords = new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(parseFloat(val.latitude), parseFloat(val.longitude));

    salesmanTrackPoints[val.id] = new nokia.maps.map.Polyline(coords, {
        polyline: {
            pen: {
                strokeColor: "#00F8",
                lineWidth: 5
            }
        },
        arrows: true
    });

    map.objects.add(salesmanTrackPoints[val.id]);

});
```

Above code is not working. Please help me if what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the `Polyline`, you need to add the array of coordinates **inside** the loop, and then **outside** of the loop you can add a single `mapobject` to the `Display` e.g.:

```
 var coords = [],
  salesmanTrackPoints;

// Loop to add all the coordinates to an array
$.each(data, function (i, val) {
  coords.push(parseFloat(val.latitude));
  coords.push(parseFloat(val.longitude));
});

// Now create the Polyline
salesmanTrackPoints = new nokia.maps.map.Polyline(coords, {
  pen: {
    strokeColor: "#22CA",
    lineWidth: 5
  },
  arrows: true
});
map.objects.add(salesmanTrackPoints);
```

Of course this may need to be altered depending upon the structure of your data. It is important to note that  `Polyline` can take an `Array` of `Coordinates` or an `Array` of `Numbers` (as individual lat, longs) as you can see from the [API Documentation](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.Polyline.html).